# In Swift, how do you get the fully-qualified name of a variable?

Tags: swift, reflection, types, mirror

Consider this code in an app called 'MyApp'...

```
class Foo{
    class Laa{
        static let laaVar = "I am laaVar"
    }
}
```

I know I can get the fully-qualified name of `Laa`, like so...

```
let laaName = String(reflecting: Foo.Laa.self)
// Returns 'MyApp.Foo.Laa'
```

but how can I get the fully-qualified name of `laaVar` (e.g. "MyApp.Foo.Laa.laaVar")?

Is that even possible?

**Bonus Question**

Given the above code, and a variable containing the string "MyApp.Foo.Laa.laaVar", how can I get the value "I am laaVar"?

I'm guessing the answer to both has something to do with reflection/mirroring.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution for your question. You might use the Objective-c runtime, especially the function `class_copyPropertyList` which describes the properties declared by a class. Example:

```
import Foundation

class Foo {
    class Laa: NSObject {
        @objc static let laaName = "I am laaVar"
    }
}

var count: CUnsignedInt = 0
let methods = class_copyPropertyList(object_getClass(Foo.Laa.self), &count)!
for i in 0 ..< count {
    let selector = property_getName(methods.advanced(by: Int(i)).pointee)
    if let key = String(cString: selector, encoding: .utf8) {
        let res = Foo.Laa.value(forKey: key)
        print("name: \(key), value: \(res ?? "")")
    }
}
```

the result is:

> name: laaName, value: I am laaVar

Comment: Interesting!  Lemme play around with that a little before voting it as accepted. (BTW, I corrected my code in the question and updated your answer accordingly. Purely a naming change.)

Comment: Quick question though... why did you do `Int(i)` instead of just `i`? Isn't it already implied as an `Int` type from the `for` loop?

Comment: @MarqueIV I had to cast such Int because of: `error: cannot convert value of type 'CUnsignedInt' (aka 'UInt32') to expected argument type 'Int'`

Comment: HA! I didn't know it treated implicit loop vars like that as a UInt32! Interesting!